# How to routing in a app when I click a link from email

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I want to open my component in Application Android (Nativescript) from a link in email, that is Click here to reset password

I have a link like this in email:

http://secsystem.domain.tk/v1/resetPassword/11E8FC9

So when I click the link from my mobile browser I need the app Launched in component resetPassword.

I use the following code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="secsystem.domain.tk" android:path="/v1/resetPassword"></data> 
        </intent-filter>
```

This code works good only in this url: http://secsystem.domain.tk/v1/resetPassword

I want to work in this url: http://secsystem.domain.tk/v1/resetPassword/11E8FC9

In routing.ts I write this code:

```
{ path: 'v1/resetPassword/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent },
```

I want to open this component when I click in link.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use [android:pathPattern](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element#path) if you want to keep the path dynamic with extra params.

Comment: Can you write code please?

Comment: It should be `android:pathPattern="/v1/resetPassword/.*"`

Comment: I try like you say and works good. But not rout in this path `v1/resetPassword/:id`, component `ResetPassIdComponent ` Can you ask me any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `android:pathPattern` when the path has dynamic parameter.

**Example**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="secsystem.domain.tk" android:path="/v1/resetPassword/.*"></data> 
 </intent-filter>
```

So far this is all about making Android understand it has to open this app when this particular URL pattern is matched. Angular has nothing to do here. If you want to navigate to particular component when app is opened with this URL pattern, then you must handle it manually.

Install [nativescript-urlhandler](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler) plugin and query the URL that was used to open the app in the app component and initiate navigation in your router accordingly.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { handleOpenURL, AppURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

@Component({
  selector: "gr-main",
  template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
    } 

    ngOnInit(){
        handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
            console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: In console show `Got the following appURL http://secsystem.domain.tk/v1/resetPassword/11E8FC9`. Now, how to open this component `ResetPassIdComponent` ?? Thank you

Comment: Parse the part of URL you want to send to router and initiate navigation with navigatByUrl.

Comment: In component app.component.ts I write  `handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {this.router.navigate(['/resetPassword']);});`  In routing.ts  `{ path: '/resetPassword', component: ResetPassIdComponent },` Now the problem is, in first in application open first component, for a few seconds open this component. How to open directly  this ResetPassIdComponent  ??

Comment: @Manoj does it work with query parameters? Because I get this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970072/nativescript-urlhandler-doesnt-intercept-queryparams-in-android-deep-link