# How to routing in other component when I click a link from email

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

When I click this link http://secsystem.domain.tk/v1/resetPassword/11E8FC9 from email, I want to open this component `ResetPassIdComponent`  in my application

I use the following code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="secsystem.domain.tk" android:pathPattern="/v1/resetPassword/.*"></data> 
        </intent-filter>
```

and in routing.ts I write this code:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'outsidelogin',
    component: outsideloginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
    ]
  },
    { path: 'v1/resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Hello, I think you can take "11E8FC9" part from url and after validating that part you can continue your process. If you share your repo (or routing.ts), we can also suggest code examples below.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I update my post.

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: I  added my solution as answer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746560/how-to-routing-in-a-app-when-i-click-a-link-from-email/53762151#53762151

Answer (score 0):

try this way you need to add just `android:pathPrefix="/v1/resetPassword"`

```
           <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="secsystem.domain.tk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/v1/resetPassword"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="secsystem.domain.tk"
                    android:pathPrefix="/v1/resetPassword"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: And my code works, but I want to navigate in this `{ path: 'v1/resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent }` not in this `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' }` 
`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Create a new empty component named routingTest.component.ts, and just console.log('routingTest!'); in ngOnInit().

**Step 2.** Try to reach that component from url, like localhost/urlTest. See if you console.log succesfully, go to next step.

**Step 3.**  Add a route definition in your Routes with a parameter as described below.

**routing.ts**

```
{ path: 'urlTest/:id', component: RoutingTestComponent}
```

After configuring your Route, now you will be able to get your url parameter. And use the ActivatedRoute in @angular/router to extract the parameters as described [here in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action):

**routingTest.component.ts**

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router'; //import library
    Constructor(public route:Router){}
    ngOnInit(){
        let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        console.log(id);
    }
```

If you console.log "id" succesfuly, it means that you can do anything you want with that.

Any question are welcome. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done in the Android manifest is all to make system understand it has to open this app when this particular URL pattern is matched. Angular has nothing to do here. If you want to navigate to particular component when app is opened with a particular URL pattern, then you must handle it manually.

Install [nativescript-urlhandler](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler) plugin and query the URL that was used to open the app in the app component and initiate navigation in your router accordingly.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
```

import { handleOpenURL, AppURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

@Component({
  selector: "gr-main",
  template: ""
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
    }

```
ngOnInit(){
    handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
        console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
    });
 }
```

}

Source: [How to routing in a app when I click a link from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746560/how-to-routing-in-a-app-when-i-click-a-link-from-email/53762151#53762151)